# Python ctypes for Fortran dll call: OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000000

Tags: python, dll, fortran, ctypes

I am attempting to call a fortran dll in python, but am running into OSerror:  exception: access violation reading 0x00000000.

The .dll function call should have the following properties:
`double FDIR(double *x,const double *a, int32_t *na, int32_t *k, double *h, double *x1,const int32_t *relparam, int32_t *m, int32_t *profile, int32_t *nlines, int32_t *nrefer, double *deltaX)`.  Additionally, I have a labview script that successfully calls the .dll, so I know that the issue is in the python script.

Below is the code that I have so far

```
from ctypes import * 
import numpy as np
#Define Variables
x = np.arange(0, 5.52602+0.197358, 0.197358)
a = [2.65477,0.859621,0.0177231,0.0001,0,4.15638,0,0,
     2.75715,-0.00442,
     0,1,0, 
     0,1,0] 
na = len(a)
k = 0
h = 0
x1 = 0
relparams = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
m = 8
profile = 1
nlines = 1
nref = 0
deltax = 0
#Conversions
a = np.asarray(a)
relparams = np.asarray(relparams, dtype = np.int32)
#Call Dll
fit_dll = cdll.LoadLibrary("mydll.dll")
#Loop dll
for x_ in x:
    fit_dll.FDIR(c_double(x_), 
                    a.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double)), 
                    c_int32(na), 
                    c_int32(k),
                    c_double(h), 
                    c_double(x1), 
                    relparams.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_int)),
                    c_int32(m),
                    c_int32(profile),
                    c_int32(nlines),
                    c_int32(nref),
                    c_double(deltax))
    print (result)
```

Is there anything here that jumps out as an obvious issue? Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:  Thanks for the help, abarnert!  I added in the argtypes and restype for the function.  And have added in the pointers for the rest of variables.  Now instead of the OSerror: exception: access violation reading 0x00000000. I am getting ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (48 bytes missing) or wrong calling convention.  Any ideas?

```
from ctypes import * 
import numpy as np

#Define Variables
x = np.arange(0, 5.52602+0.197358, 0.197358)
a = [2.65477,0.859621,0.0177231,0.0001,0,4.15638,0.0001,0.0001,
    2.75715,-0.00442, # linear baseline
    0,1,0, # etalon 1
    0,1,0] # etalon 2
na = len(a)
k = 0
h = 0
x1 = 0#x0
relparams = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
m = 8
profile = 1
nlines = 1
nref = 0
deltax = 0
#Conversions

a = np.asarray(a)
relparams = np.asarray(relparams, dtype = np.int32)
#Call Dll

fit_dll = cdll.LoadLibrary("mydll.dll")
#Loop dll

#Setting argtypes

fit_dll.FDIR.argtypes = [POINTER(c_double), #1 - x
                        POINTER(c_double),#2 - a
                        POINTER(c_int),#3 - na 
                        POINTER(c_int),#4 - k
                        POINTER(c_double),#5 - h
                        POINTER(c_double), #6 - x1
                        POINTER(c_int), #7 - relparam
                        POINTER(c_int), #8 - m
                        POINTER(c_int), #9 - profile
                        POINTER(c_int),#10 - nlines
                        POINTER(c_int),#11 - nref
                        POINTER(c_double)] #12 - deltax

# Setting restype
fit_dll.FDIR.restype  = c_double
#  Define Types
LP_c_double = POINTER(c_double)
LP_c_int = POINTER(c_int)

#Loop dll
print (LP_c_double(c_double(deltax)))
x_ = 0
fit_dll.FDIR(LP_c_double(c_double(x_)), #1
                a.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double)), #2
                LP_c_int(c_int(na)), #3
                LP_c_int(c_int(k)), #4
                LP_c_double(c_double(h)),#5 
                LP_c_double(c_double(x1)), #6
                relparams.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_int)), #7
                LP_c_int(c_int(m)), #8
                LP_c_int(c_int(profile)), #9 
                LP_c_int(c_int(nlines)), #10
                LP_c_int(c_int(nref)), #11
                LP_c_double(c_double(deltax))) #12
```

Comment: You should set the `argtypes` and `restype` for the function. Then ctypes can validate that you got the paeans right (and, better, you can let it convert most of them for you to make each call nicer) and tell you if that’s the problem.

Comment: The other thing you can do is run this inside lldb/gdb/VS/whatever and see where the segfault happens and what value it’s trying to access.

Comment: Meanwhile, assuming your translation for Fortran to C is correct, the interface to the function is a whole bunch of pointers, but you’re only passing pointers (to arrays or individual values) to a few of them; the rest, you’re passing int32 and the like. If the Fortran code tries to use one of those ints as a pointer, of course it’s going to end up dereferencing 0 and segfaulting. This one is probably your error, but the first step toward fixing it is the same as the first step toward further debugging (argtypes), so do that first.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I added in the argtypes and restype for the function.  And have added in the pointers for the rest of variables.  Now instead of the OSerror: exception: access violation reading 0x00000000. I am getting ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (48 bytes missing) or wrong calling convention.  (Updated in original question with the current code for clarity) Any ideas?